# Anchor link from input and submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a little form and I intend to allow the user to jump to a section by entering a number and this becoming an anchor link:

```
Jump to <input type="text" value="" name="a_gobox" id="a_gobox" /> 
<input type="image" class="button" name="submit" src="/images/gobutton.png" alt="Go" />
```

So if the user enters "7" then I want the hash anchor of the page to change to `#section7`.

It is important that the actual hash value changes in the address bar as well as reflecting this on the page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is this without jQuery?

Comment: I do have jQuery on that page, but it is important that the address bar changes as well as just the hash variable on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply do:

```
window.location.hash = '#' + $('#a_gobox').val();
```

Comment: The `'#'` part seems to be optional (in Firefox, at least - haven't tested in other browsers), but this would be the general approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
   var which_number = $('#a_gobox').val(),
       section_to_jump_to = '#section_' + which_number;
    window.location.hash= section_to_jump_to; 
});
```

And a little fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ftWZh/1/